# how to convert date to number of year in android and number of month

Tags: android

I want to get which day of year is it.
a year have 365 days . I want to get which day base on the data , i have .
for example :
my date is : 2017/01/03  ---> base on this data I found that it means day 2.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to get your desired output:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // get calendar object instance
cal.setTime("set your time here"); // set your desired time here, it can be as Date object, if you've millis then use setTimeInMillis();
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR); // get day of year like this
```

Comment: time? i do not need time

Comment: @balvin you need to pass a `Date` as a parameter to `setTime`  to initialize the calendar with your date.

Comment: @how can i convert to persian . i mean now i have day of year but not in persian time?